# Происхождение слова "усугубить"

Tags: этимология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какое происхождение у слова "усугубить", "сугубо"? С чем оно родственное: губа? Губить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С "ГУБИТЬ" родственные связи есть. Усугубить - от устаревшего прилагательного сугубый, от него осталось наречие сугубо(вдвойне, вдвое больше нормы).Усугубить - сделать сугубым, согнутым пополам.

Фасмер пишет:"По-видимому, из *sǫ- (см. су- I) и к.* gub-; родств. гибкий, губить, гнуть. Ст.-слав. соу- вместо *сѫ-, возм., объясняется ассимиляцией гласных. Ср. др.-прусск. dwigubbus "двойной", лит. dvìgubas". Всё логично: согнуть вдвое= вдвойне. Усугубить несчастье - сделать его больше вдвое, сгубить.

Comment: Людмила, вы дали неплохой ответ, но смущают некоторые факты: в  выражении "сугубо моё мнение", слово "сугубо", значит - "только", а слова: "загубить", "пагубить" - безвозвратно  испортить, поэтому "губить" никак не вяжется с "гнуть", ближе - "убить", которое, по моему мнению, происходит от "бить"( губить - грубо бить, безжалостно, приводя к гибели). А слово "сугубо" я бы робко приблизил к "моим губам", т.е. - "сугубо моё мнение" - мнение, сошедшее с моих губ, сопричастное лишь мне, так же как устный ответ - ответ сошедший с уст. Но это сугубо моё мнение, не более того.

Comment: Словарь Цыганенко: Праславянское губити-глагол с тем же корнем губ(гнуть), что и в слове гибнуть, это чередование у//ы > и. Губити - каузатив -повелит. накл.к *gybati>гибати(гнуть). Собственно губить- заставлять гнуться, сгибаться, гибнуть.Образовано от "губа" - изгиб суши, бухта, в 14-15 веках означало ещё и "гибель, пагуба"."Сугубо"означает не "только", а "именно, особенно, подчёркнуто" - та же тема, что и в "усиленно", потому что "сугубый"-двойной, увеличенный вдвое.В др.-русск. было ещё СУГУБИНА - двойное количество.Это есть в учебнике др.-русск. яз.

Comment: Так что слову ГУБА родственно, но в другом значении - изгиб суши, всё тот же корень, как в СГИБАТЬ.

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ ТОЛКОВОГО СЛОВАРЯ

СУГУБЫЙ, Особенный, исключительный (по сравнению с чем-л. обычным). С-ое внимание. С. интерес. Сугубо, нареч. С. гражданская внешность. Надо поговорить с. конфиденциально.

Значение этого слова изменялось по следующей схеме: согнутый пополам (от сгибать), вдвое больший, двойной,например: Отдать заем сугубиною, сугубо, отдать сугубицу.

Затем: повышенный,  усиленный: "Красота была для него святыней, а «женственность» — святыней сугубой". Салтыков-Щедрин.

И наконец, современное значение: исключительный, особый, особенный: Этот образ разрабатывался Пушкиным в сугубо романтическом духе.Молодой Толстой — сугубый рационалист в духе XVIII столетия.